# dplyr conditional summation

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data_frame(x = sample(0:100, 50, replace = T), 
                 y = sample(c(T, F), 50, replace = T))
```

I would like to create a third column `z` that will be the sum of column `x`, but only if there are more than 3 `true`s in a row in column `y`.
Is there a vectorized way to do it with `dplyr`? I don't even know how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a grouping variable with `rleid` from `data.table` and get the `sum` of 'x' if there are more than 3 elements (`n() >3`) and `if` `all` the elements in 'y' are TRUE or `else` return `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(y)) %>% 
  mutate(Sum = if(n() > 3 & all(y)) sum(x) else NA_integer_) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

---

It can be also done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  Sum := sum(x) * NA^(!((.N > 3) & all(y))), .(grp = rleid(y))]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question did not specify what values to use if there are not 3 TRUE values so we will use 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

sum3 <- function(z) all(z[, "y"]) * sum(z[, "x"])
df %>% mutate(sum = rollapplyr(df, 3, sum3, by.column = FALSE, fill = 0))
```

giving:

```
 # A tibble: 50 x 3
       x y       sum
   <int> <lgl> <int>
 1    92 TRUE      0
 2    94 TRUE      0
 3    28 TRUE    214
 4    83 FALSE     0
 5    64 TRUE      0
 6    52 FALSE     0
 7    74 FALSE     0
 8    13 TRUE      0
 9    66 TRUE      0
10    71 FALSE     0
# ... with 40 more rows
```